# MySQL - Selecting rows based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects users from `members` table if `mem_id` does not exists in the `swipes` table. The query goes as follows:

```
SELECT members.* FROM members
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE (mem_id IN (swp_by, swp_to) AND :mem IN (swp_by)))
```

The above query does half of my job. However, I want to add up a couple of more conditions here. In `swipes` table, there are two fields namely `swp_type` and `swp_status`. Here `swp_type` has `ENUM` values `left, right, top` which shows the card swiped are left, right or top (like tinder) and `swp_status` also has `ENUM` values `requested, accepted, declined, unmatched` which states if the friend requested is still in requested state, or is accepted, or declined or later after acceptance was unmatched. Now I want to modify the above query so that it accepts these two tables in conditions and returns result based on them.

Let's take example:

Say, there are two users 1 & 2. Right now there are no records in the `swipes` table so user 1 & 2 can see each other.

Now, say if user 1 LEFT swiped user 2, then:

```
swp_by: 1, swp_to: 2, swp_type: left, swp_status: requested
```

For the above data, user 1 LEFT swiped user 2 (which means user 1 does not want to get matched with user 2) so they won't be able to see each other anymore.

Now, say if user 1 either RIGHT or TOP swiped user 2, then:

```
swp_by: 1, swp_to: 2, swp_type: right/top, swp_status: requested
```

For the above data, user 1 can't see user 2 anymore but user 2 can see user 1 as the `swp_type` here is right and `swp_status` is `requested`.

Now say, for the above data `swp_status` is not `requested` but anything else except `requested` say (accepted/declined) then both users won't be able to see each other anymore again. This is what I want to add to my current query as a condition.

My current query does half the job by displaying members who are not present in `swipes` table considering `swp_by` & `swp_to`. I want to add the conditions for `swp_type` and `swp_status` as explained above.

**What I tried?**

I tried the following but it ends up giving weird results. It returned all the members when according to the data it should only return member with `mem_id` `8` as it does not exists in the swipes table in relation to user 1 and user `12` as it is `right` and `requested` and user `15` as it is `top` and `requested`.

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE (mem_id IN (swp_by, swp_to) AND 1 IN (swp_by)) AND swp_type != 'left' AND swp_status = 'requested')
```

Hence, I think that is not how I have to place conditions.

Fiddle Here: [DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tL9CNPU8816s9Z7GWTECjS/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going out on a limb here because I confess that I had a very difficult time following your explanation. In the end I had no idea whether you were describing credit card processing, a dating service or something else. So you may have to "adjust" the SQL based on any misunderstanding I might have.

To better understand my SQL, I have taken your original SQL:

```
SELECT members.* FROM members
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE (mem_id IN (swp_by, swp_to) AND 1 IN (swp_by)))
```

and recast it to what I believe is the equivalent and used that as a starting point:

```
SELECT members.* FROM members
WHERE mem_id <> 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE mem_id = swp_to AND swp_by = 1
)
```

I ended up with:

```
SELECT * from members
WHERE mem_id <> 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE
      members.mem_id = swp_by and 1 = swp_to OR
      members.mem_id = swp_to and 1 = swp_by
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE mem_id <> 1
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE swp_by = members.mem_id AND swp_to = 1
  AND swp_type <> 'left' AND swp_status = 'requested'
)
```

This is a union. The first piece is:

```
SELECT * from members
WHERE mem_id <> 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE
      members.mem_id = swp_by and 1 = swp_to OR
      members.mem_id = swp_to and 1 = swp_by
)
```

This is attempting to select all rows that "do not exist in the swipes table in relation to user 1", which would be with your sample data `mem_id 8`. Now perhaps it should only be checking `swp_by=1` and `swp_to=8` and not also `swp_by=8` and `swp_to=1` (or vice-versa). If so, you can make that adjustment.

The second piece of the union adds rows that have a corresponding swipe (`swp_by` set to `mem_id`) with `swp_type` not equal to `'left'` and `swp_status` equal to `'requested'` with `swp_to` equal to `1`. I have used this criteria based on you sample data and the rows you said you expected returned:

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE mem_id <> 1
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM swipes WHERE swp_by = members.mem_id AND swp_to = 1
  AND swp_type <> 'left' AND swp_status = 'requested'
)
```

If the SQL is not exactly what you need, I would think only a slight adjustment should be required.

[See Db-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uMnzjikFLjxSKMgvhrCKTm/2)

The above can also be accomplished using inner and outer joins:

```
SELECT members.* from members LEFT JOIN swipes ON
  mem_id = swp_by AND 1 = swp_to OR
  mem_id = swp_to and 1 = swp_by
WHERE mem_id <> 1 AND swp_id is NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT members.* FROM members JOIN swipes ON
  mem_id = swp_by AND
  swp_to = 1 AND
  swp_type <> 'left' AND
  swp_status = 'requested'
WHERE mem_id <> 1
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hCco9AcwViBGCcm8Y1JuPA/1)

Looking at the above suggest that there is an opportunity to remove the union:

```
SELECT DISTINCT members.* from members LEFT JOIN swipes ON
  mem_id = swp_by AND 1 = swp_to OR
  mem_id = swp_to AND 1 = swp_by
WHERE mem_id <> 1 AND
  swp_id is NULL OR (
    mem_id = swp_by AND
    swp_to = 1 AND  
    swp_type <> 'left' AND
    swp_status = 'requested'
  )
ORDER BY mem_id
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/723HJVPSWVkhBMV9dHpUVT/1)

Comment: I am making a dating app like Tinder or Tantan and this query was to display the cards for swipes as in Tinder...

Comment: I sort of figured that after a long while, But having never been on any of those sites, it was all foreign to me, such as "swiping left". And "display the cards for swipes" means nothing to me either.

Comment: I understand.. And I totally understand that you have vested upon A LOT OF TIME to my question which I am very much thankful about.. I am reading your answer at the moment.. I will update in a moment please wait..

Comment: It would be so much easier if you just said something like: For user 1, display all rows in members such that there is at least one row for that mem_id in swipes such that swp_to is 1 and swp_by is that mem_id and swp_type <> 'left' and swp_status = 'requested'. If that is, in fact, what the condition is. But I am left trying to glean that from what was for me a confusing description and SQL which does not return the correct results. So that's why I offer the disclaimer. Now this may be very clear to somebody else and it's just my shortcoming.

Comment: You are right.. I should learn writing proper descriptions. Thanks :) I tried your code and it gives the perfect result. You won't believe that just 10 mins ago I took my pen and jotted down the required output and then you answered, tried your query and boom.. there it is.. See here I https://prnt.sc/s5rmui 

Again... thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: It may give the perfect result without it being logically correct. I could have just said `select * from members where mem_id in (8, 12, 15)` and you would get the 3 rows you are looking for but that would not be the correct logic. The question is whether I am looking at the right columns and making the correct checks?

Comment: Can we come in a chat? I know it's solved but still.. to check logics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212491/discussion-between-booboo-and-code-with-desire).

Comment: I sent a message... Check!